# Subtract Binary Numbers with 1`s Complement

Tags: numerical-methods, binary

I'm trying to figure out how to subtract two binary numbers with a complementary one or two,
When I need to address carrier and when not? Do I need to solve the problem in decimal numbers? And simultaneously see the answer in binary numbers?
For example:

```
(10101010) - (1101101) 
complement of (1101101) is 0010010
then i take the first number and add it to the complement 
10101010+
 0010010
 _______
10111100

the result of subtraction those number is : 111101 so what i`m understanding is i have  
a carrier so i`m take 111100 + 1 and i get the final result : 111101
```

now I`ll take another two numbers

```
(111001) - (10011)
```

i`m doing the same procces and i dont get the right answer. 
what should i do?
Do I need to complete the number to the eight bits? That is if you need to add zeros then the complement they will become one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$10101010 - 1101101 = 10101010 - 01101101 = 10101010 + (-01101101)= 10101010 + (10010010 + 1)=10101010 + 10010011 = 00111101$

And you can check that $00111101+1101101=10101010$

---

$111001 - 10011 = 00111001 - 00010011 = 00111001 + (-00010011) = 00111001 + (11101100 + 1) = 00111001 + 11101101 = 00100110$

And you can check that $00100110+10011=111001$

---

So to compute $a-b$, you start by making sure you have $8$ bits for both numbers and add $0$s on the left otherwise, then you compute $-b$ by negating all the bits and adding $1$ and then you compute $a+(-b)$.

Comment: there is a difference between 2`s and 1`s? , in 2`s i`m adding one and flip, and 1`s i`m just flipping?

Comment: Yes and no. You flip *before* adding $1$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add by just taking complement of a number.First you have to convert negative number into 2's complement.

> ```
> 2's complement
>
>  First take complement 
>
>  add 1 to flipped number
> ```

a=(010101010) - b=(001101101)

2's complement of b is  110010011

now $a+b^{'}$

> a= 010101010 (170)
>
> $b^{'}$=110010011 (-109)
>
> c= 000111101 (61)

Comment: alternative way of finding 2's complement is $2^n-b$ where n is number of bits.for example:- 10011 here n=5 so calculate $32-19$=13 and write 13 into binary form 01101(2's complement of 10011)